# Sticky footer overlaps the main content "WordPress Template"

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know there are solutions about sticky footer but I tried them all. What I intend to do is to stick the footer at the bottom of the page whether content is short or long without using position:fixed and fix footer height.

the footer does sticks at the bottom when there's not much content on the footer but when there's contents like the sample below it overlaps the main content.

See the page here: [Click to see the page](http://markestrada.co.uk/wdch/)

[image]

```
footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
background:#333;
padding:10px 0; /*paddingtop+bottom 20*/
}

.wrapper{
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

#main{
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:45px;   /* Height+padding(top and botton) of the footer */
   height:100%;
}
```

Okay now it doesn't over lap the content but I have a big gap in between the content and footer when the content is short or empty. How can I get rid of the scroll bar when the content is short and vice versa.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` and adding instead `margin-top: -120px;` should fix your problem. The css will be:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    margin-top: -120px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Well that fixed the overlapping but when the content is short/empty there is a big gap at the bottom of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `footer`'s height is much greater than `25px`, but your `#main`'s bottom padding is only `20px` (`footer`'s total vertical padding) + `25px`.  The actual computed height according to my inspection is `245px`.  So try this:

```
padding-bottom: 265px; /* 245px (footer height) + 20px (footer total vert padding) */
```

Answer (score 0):

**From my example**:
`overflow: auto` should be assigned to `.module-content` and it should have a `bottom-padding` with the `height` of footer.

```
#mycontent .module-content {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
#footer {
    color: red;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VQ27K/)

Comment: so in my case, I'm doing this for WP template.

#mycontent will be my #main?

http://markestrada.co.uk/wdch/news/ this is the big gap I mentioned in my previous reply to the other person above.